# navigate between current and previous tab or split

Tags: neovim, split, navigation

Is it possible to navigate between two previously used tabs and/or splits?

I understand why buffers are best to use, and that I can use `:b#` to achieve what I want, but I have wondered if this was possible with tabs and/or splits.

#### Tabs:

Sometimes, if the buffer list gets long, I like to keep a few important ones in tabs. Can I jump to the last tab I was just previously in? (just like `tmux last-window`)

#### Splits:

We all (hopefully!) use splits when there is enough room, I've don't really need more than 4 splits, but as I cannot find an answer anywhere else. Can I jump to the previous split? (just like `tmux last-pane`)

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: One think you might like to check out is the arglist - it's like the buffer list but you can add or remove files to have only the important ones - it's like a VIP buffer list. See `:help arglist` and the famous vimcasts for an demonstration of what I'm talking about: http://vimcasts.org/episodes/meet-the-arglist/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To go to the last visited tab do: <kbd>g</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> (see `:help tab-page-commands`)

To go to the last visited window split do:<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> (see `:help window-move-cursor`)